# Jquery tabs and CakePHP

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I am using jquery tabs within my CakePHP project. Here is my Script:

```
$(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
 });
```

Here is my code for the tabs

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Statistics', array('action' => 'overview_stats', $current_user['id']))?></li>
        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Orders', array('action' => 'overview_orders', $current_user['id']))?></li>
        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Past Orders', array('action' => 'overview_past_orders', $current_user['id']))?></li>
        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Blog Pages', array('action' => 'overview_blog_pages', $current_user['id']))?></li>
        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Chextands', array('action' => 'overview_chextands', $current_user['id']))?></li>


    </ul>
</div>
```

Each time I click on the tabs, The entire page is rendered within each tab. Is there a way to only render the view within my .ctp file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the layout of those actions to be 'ajax':

```
$this->layout = 'ajax';
```

That way you do not load the entire layout inside the tab.

You must do this in the controller in the respective action

Comment: When I added that to the action, the entire page changed to a blank layout rather than just within the tab

Comment: Do you have an ajax.ctp layout? Create a layout file called `ajax.ctp` and in it put: `<?php echo $content_for_layout; ?>`

Comment: Make sure you are doing this for the actions: `overview_stats`, `overview_orders`, `overview_past_orders`, `overview_blog_pages`, `overview_chextands` and NOT the action for the page that HOLDS the tabs.